# name does not exist in the namespace of wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

summary of soInput.xaml:

```
        xmlns:core="clr-namespace:MyProject.Fun.Core"
         xmlns:behave="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"


       <TextBox Name="txtValue"
                     Margin="0"
                     Style="{DynamicResource soTextBox}"
                     TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                     Height="50"
                     Foreground="#FF363636"
                     FontSize="18.667"
                     FontWeight="Bold"
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                     IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled,ElementName=Input}"
                     Text="{Binding soValue,ElementName=Input,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                     GotFocus="txtValue_GotFocus"
                     LostFocus="txtValue_LostFocus">
            <behave:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:TextBoxKeyboardBehavior/>
            </behave:Interaction.Behaviors>
       </TextBox>
```

soInput.xaml.cs:

```
       namespace MyProject.Fun
{
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

public partial class soInput : UserControl, IComponentConnector
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty soErrorProperty =   DependencyProperty.Register("soError", typeof(string), typeof(soInput));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty soHelpDescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("soHelpDescription", typeof(string), typeof(soInput), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty soHelpTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("soHelpTitle", typeof(string), typeof(soInput), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty soLabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("soLabel", typeof(string), typeof(soInput));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty soValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("soValue", typeof(string), typeof(soInput));

    public soInput()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Input_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }


    private void txtValue_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void txtValue_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public string soError
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) base.GetValue(soErrorProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(soErrorProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string soHelpDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) base.GetValue(soHelpDescriptionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(soHelpDescriptionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string soHelpTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) base.GetValue(soHelpTitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(soHelpTitleProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string soLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) base.GetValue(soLabelProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(soLabelProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string soValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) base.GetValue(soValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(soValueProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
 }
```

TextBoxKeyboardBehavior.cs:

```
    using MyProject.Fun.Helpers;
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Interactivity;

     namespace MyProject.Fun.Core
   {
public partial class TextBoxKeyboardBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        base.AssociatedObject.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(this.AssociatedObject_GotFocus);
        base.AssociatedObject.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(this.AssociatedObject_LostFocus);
    }
    private void AssociatedObject_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = base.AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("keyboardBtn", base.AssociatedObject) as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click -= new RoutedEventHandler(this.btn_Click);
        }
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
    private void AssociatedObject_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = base.AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("keyboardBtn", base.AssociatedObject) as Button;
        if (button == null)
        {
            base.AssociatedObject.ApplyTemplate();
        }
        button = (base.AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("keyboardBtn", base.AssociatedObject) as Button);
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.btn_Click);
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(base.AssociatedObject, TextBox.TextProperty);
        Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = bindingExpression.DataItem;
        binding.Path = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path;
        binding.Mode = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Mode;
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger;
        binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated;
        binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated;
        binding.NotifyOnValidationError = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.NotifyOnValidationError;
        binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors;
        keyboard.TextTxt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
        bool visibility = NavigationHelper.MainLayout.ModalBackground.Visibility != Visibility.Visible;
        Util.ShowKeyboardForm(keyboard, visibility);
    }
    private object GetValue(string path, object dataItem)
    {
        string[] array = path.Split(new char[]
        {
            '.'
        });
        object obj = null;
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(path);
        object result;
        if (property != null)
        {
            obj = property.GetValue(dataItem, null);
            result = obj;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] array2 = array;
            for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
            {
                string name = array2[i];
                if (obj == null)
                {
                    property = dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(name);
                    obj = property.GetValue(dataItem, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name);
                    obj = property.GetValue(obj, null);
                }
            }
            result = obj;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

error:
The name "TextBoxKeyboardBehavior" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyProject.Fun.Core".
in backup of project it does work but in this case does not work !!!
all code are in same project and work last night but today does not work !